# Negative parabola on a log base 2 scale

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am looking for a function $f(x)$ that satisfies these conditions:

$$ 
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
<0,  & \text{$x<0.5$} \\
0,  & \text{$x=0.5$} \\
1,  & \text{$x=1$} \\
0,  & \text{$x=2$}\\
<0,  & \text{$x>2$}
\end{cases}
$$

It's like a negative parabola, that peaks at $f(1) = 1$, except the x axis is on a non-linear scale, where $0.5$ is the same distance from $1$ as $2$ is to $1$.

So my thinking is that the x axis should be a log base $2$ scale (since $2^{-1} = 0.5$, $2^0 = 1$, $2^1= 2$). But I don't know how to design a function that accomplishes this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach would be
$$ f(x) = (1-\log_2 x)(1+\log_2 x) = 1 - \log_2(x)^2 $$

If you need your $f$ to be defined for $x\le 0$, this won't work, though.

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x)=1-|\log_2(x)|$?

This works too, but the domain is $x > 0$.